# Asterisk the whole text without showing a single word flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have use the obscure text, however it still shows the character before the asterisk (can be shown at the image). How do i make it completely hide every character [image]

Answer (score 0):

setting obscureText to true on the TextField works for me.

In addition, I would set enableSuggestions to false and autocorrect to false.

It could look like this:

```
TextField(
   obscureText: true,
   enableSuggestions: false,
   autocorrect: false,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user is typing in a password text field on a mobile device, it is common for the last character to be briefly displayed before it is obscured. This is because the system is designed to provide visual feedback to the user, so they know that the character they just typed has been registered by the device.

In Flutter, the `obscureText` property can be set to true to indicate that the text input should be treated as a password field. When `obscureText` is set to true, the text entered by the user will be obscured by dots or asterisks to protect the privacy of the user. However, even with `obscureText` set to `true`, it is still possible for the last character to be briefly displayed before being obscured. This is because this behavior is expected on mobile devices.

In summary, the line you provided is pointing out that the brief display of the last typed character in a password text field is a common behavior on mobile devices, even when the `obscureText` property is set to true.

You can read more about this in this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/56794) of the **Flutter** official repository on **Github**.

Comment: so is there a way to hide it completly?

Comment: as from this PR it is cleared that you cannot achieve it with the properties TextField is providing. Maybe there are other techniques by which you can achieve it but i don't have knowledge of that right now.